# First argument to get_object_or_404() must be a Model, Manager, or QuerySet, not 'function'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to show some data based on the user_id in the database but it keeps getting this ValueError. Can anyone help me find out what I am doing wrong?

This is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import user

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'pages/index.html')

def user(request, user_id):
    profile = get_object_or_404(user, pk=user_id)
    context = {
        'profile' : profile
    }
    return render(request, 'user/user.html', context)
```

Comment: Since you defined a function with the name `user` that has overwritten the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you defined a function named `user`, that has overwritten the reference to the `user` model here.

You can use an alias in your import like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import user as UserModel

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'pages/index.html')

def user(request, user_id):
    profile = get_object_or_404(UserModel, pk=user_id)
    context = {
        'profile' : profile
    }
    return render(request, 'user/user.html', context)
```

That being said, according to the [PEP-8 style guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) the names of classes should be written in `CamelCase`, and that of functions in `lowercase_separated_by_underscores`. So if comply to these guidelines, you should rename your `user` model to `User`.

Since Django has already a model named [**`User`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) (in `django.contrib.auth`), you might want to rename to `Profile` for example.

Comment: Thanks! Trying to change my user model to User it shows this


ImportError: cannot import name 'user' from 'user.models' (/Users/Rudolph/Desktop/dev/badges/user/models.py

but changed everything and cannot save it. Any ideas how to solve this in the future?

Comment: @RudolphMusngi: if you rename the class, you of course need to alter the `import` statements as well, since `from app.models import user` then no longer works.